# How to make MSBuild detect output-input tool chain dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

#### tl;dr

I added the output of one tool (MIDL) as input to another tool (mine) to the project.
Now MSBuild no longer tracks the MIDL output correctly.

#### Long story

I added `PIATest.idl` to a Visual Studio C++ project.
That file is compiled into `PIATest.tlb` using MIDL.
If I delete `PIATest.tlb` and build the project (no rebuild!)
then MIDL is automatically called again to build the missing `PIATest.tlb`, as expected.
The project remains *up-to-date* thereafter.

Now I added *that* `PIATest.tlb` as file to the project because
I've set up a Visual Studio property page and build targets that allow
me to customize the call to `tlbimp.exe` to create a primary interop assembly.
This all works well; if I *compile* `PIATest.tlb` then `tlbimp.exe` creates a primary interop dll and if I modify `PIATest.idl` then MIDL and `tlbimp.exe` are both called in the correct order.

However, if I now delete `PIATest.tlb` then it is no longer rebuild.
It seems that because `PIATest.tlb` has been added to the project,
it has automatically been removed from the list of outputs of the MIDL tool.
`Target Midl` keeps reporting *"All outputs are up-to-date."*

MSBuild does notice that the project contains a non-existing file (`PIATest.tlb`), so it marks the project as out-of-date and executes the `build` task. But since MIDL won't recreate the TLB file, it just proceeds with the `TlbImp` task which fails due to the missing input.

**Question:** How can I tell MIDL/MSbuild to keep treating `PIATest.tlb` as output?

Below are the files I imported into the project to add the *Primary Interop Assembly* tool chain.
For the sake of simplicity for this post, these omit all the parameters for `tlbimp.exe` and just create a fake interop dll.

### PrimaryInteropAssembly.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/build/2009/properties">
  <ItemType Name="PrimaryInteropAssembly" DisplayName="Primary Interop Assembly"/>
  <ContentType Name="PrimaryInteropAssembly" ItemType="PrimaryInteropAssembly" DisplayName="Primary Interop Assembly"/>
  <FileExtension Name=".tlb" ContentType="PrimaryInteropAssembly"/>
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```

### PrimaryInteropAssembly.targets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)PrimaryInteropAssembly.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="PrimaryInteropAssembly">
      <Targets>TlbImp</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="TlbImp" Condition="'@(PrimaryInteropAssembly)' != ''" BeforeTargets="AfterMidl">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PrimaryInteropAssembly>
        <Command>type %(Identity) > %(Filename).interop.dll</Command>
        <Outputs>%(Filename).interop.dll</Outputs>
      </PrimaryInteropAssembly>
    </ItemGroup>

    <CustomBuild
      Sources="@(PrimaryInteropAssembly)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="true"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(TLogLocation)"
      ErrorListRegex="(?'FILENAME'.+):(?'LINE'\d+):(?'COLUMN'\d+): (?'CATEGORY'error|warning): (?'TEXT'.*)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

#### Edit

After some more digging, I came to the conclusion that the culprit lies in the UpToDateChecker of Visual Studio. It removes or no longer adds the `.tlb` file to the outputs of the `midl` tool; hence midl is not called. So I filed a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/UpToDateChecker-doesnt-work-correctly-a/1400875?port=1025&fsid=3d44702f-3690-4de9-b992-fda30133ad69&entry=myfeedback&ref=native&refTime=1618738548137&refUserId=04ca0f06-f386-6327-933b-8b2cce5cfdc7).

Does anybody have an idea how to work around this by modifying `PrimaryInteropAssembly.targets`?

Comment: I think you could use [Inputs and outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019) node for `TlbImp` target.  That could make the file as output file for build. Use this:`<Target Name="TlbImp" Condition="'@(PrimaryInteropAssembly)' != ''" Inputs="@(PrimaryInteropAssembly)" Outputs="$(OutDir)PIATest.tlb" BeforeTargets="AfterMidl">`

Comment: @Sara Liu, thanks for the proposal. The problem is that the _midl_ task is missing its output `PIATest.tlb`. If I use your proposal, then the tlbimp task won't be executed as soon as midl has (re)created `PIATest.tlb`. It rightfully reports that "all outputs are up to date".